# Rewrite rule of iis is not working

Tags: windows, iis, url-rewriting

I want to make a redirection like that:

localhost:80/api/* to localhost:8080/api/*

I'm trying to use iis to do this task but is not working, the rule that i have 
used is :

(Pattern)(RE) ^api/(.*)
(Action)(Rewrite) http://localhost:8080/{R:1}

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6svRA.png

How can it be done?

Comment: Your rule it is better to be added to your question. (Not only as an image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule looks correct. I think the problem that you don't have ARR installed/enabled. Please follow this steps:

1) You need to install [ARR module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) for IIS

2) Enable ARR. On the `Application Request Routing` page, select `Enable proxy`

3) Restart IIS and check that your rewrite rule is working