# IIS URL Rewrite with Incoming URL

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have a strange business case where I need any time a URL is called on my web server that it is re written with the incoming URL.

Example:

Incoming URL

/site/1

URL that it is going to

/innerlink/2

In the browsers URL
/innerline/2 would show /site/1

If you can answer this question or get me to some material that could help me in doing this it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of this approach "URL rewriting". In IIS you can achieve it with URL rewrite module. 
In your case when you just need to rewrite `/site/1` to `/innerlink/2` you need to do the following:

1. Install [URL rewrite module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) for IIS (it might be already installed)
2. In your web.config you need to add this rewrite rule:

.

```
<rule name="Laravel5" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^site/1$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/innerlink/2" />
</rule>
```

3. And now if you will open in your browser this link `{YOUR DOMAIN, IP OR HOSTNAME}/site/1` it will make request to `/innerlink/2` (but browser will keep showing `/site/1`)

P.S. Also you can find some useful rewrite/redirect rules in this article: https://host4asp.net/top-iis-rewrite-rules/

Comment: I need to do this where /site/1 is dynamic? I need it to be from whatever referrer it is coming from like it could be from /home/1 or /web/2. Does the IIS Inbound rule still work in that scenario?

Comment: You can create multiple rules for that. Or if you have some pattern between source and destination URL, then you might need to have complex rule with regexp

Comment: what about from different host names? like bob.com/site going to mysite.com/help showing bob.com/site ?

Comment: A very similar approach, but you need to also install ARR module. You can find my similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034128/rewrite-rule-of-iis-is-not-working/47050501#47050501